# TYPO3: BaseModel?

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-8.x, typo3-8.7.x

In a TYPO3 8.7 extbase extension with a lot of similar items, I have a BaseRepository that is extended for each item. So all items will share those methods. That looks like good practice to me.

I wonder if it also recommended & possible to have something like a BaseEntity in the **model**, where properties, getters and setters for common attributes would be defined and inherited by the final model classes? Or doesn't make that sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that's possible and I use it quite often even if the models are not so resembling.
Like that it's always easy to apply some functions to all classes in the controller / model or repository.
So you can extend all models from an own abstract model-class, all repositories from an abstract repository class and all controllers from an abstract controller class.
The own abstract classes extend then the corresponding common classes of extbase.
If you make it always like that even with empty abstract classes it's always easy to apply any functions still later.

Related to Model-Objects it has to be considered that there might exist Value-Objects and Entity-Objects. So it might be required to define for each type an own abstract class if both types are used.

Comment: Thanks! I made an `abstract class AbstractBaseEntity extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\DomainObject\AbstractEntity` and it works very well

Comment: The real "magic" has to come then from the properties and/or functions in the new abstract class(es) ;-)